# Preload fonts with Create React App JS bundle

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, preload

Despite following the [recommended approach](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) to self-hosting custom fonts in my React application (bootstrapped with Create React App, unejected), I am experiencing a flash of unstyled text upon load (the below GIF is slowed down):

[image: example]

My folder structure is:

```
- src
-- fonts
--- custom-font.woff
- index.scss
```

```
// index.scss

@font-face {
  font-family: "CustomFont";
  src: url("./fonts/custom-font.woff") format("woff");
}
```

I have tried:

- Moving the fonts to the `public` folder with a `rel="preload"` tag in the `index.html`, but then the `index.scss` in the `src` folder can't resolve the module when included in the `@font-face` at-rule.
- Adding loading state in the component, with a `useEffect` hook to set the loading state as the component is mounted, but it appears the font is only loaded in after the effect takes place, so the problem remains.

Is there a recommended approach to loading in fonts that stops the FOUT, or delaying component render until the font is fully loaded?

Please note:

- I am not interested in Google Fonts, or other CDNs, only self-hosted fonts
- I do not want to eject

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794703/load-fonts-synchronously-with-css and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712242/wait-for-fonts-to-load-before-rendering-web-page may be help

Comment: @HardikGodhani neither links are relevant, or they have been attempted (as per question)

Comment: try into your font-face `font-display: swap;`. more about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display