# how to draw fontawesome(version >=5.0) in canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, unicode, font-awesome

### I want to draw fontawesome icons on the canvas.

Below is my code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<script>
    var content = '\uF006';
    var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    context.font = '48px Material Design Icons';
    context.fillText(content, 100, 100);
    context.strokeText(content, 100, 100);
</script>
```

I have imported the font files and linked it. But it doesn't works:
[it just show a rectangle which is empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV3Zu.png)

can you tell me why?

one interesting thing is that it works when I link the fontawesome version 4.5 online address : [enter link description here](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css)

where the difference between the two version?

Comment: How did you import the font files and link them?

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570801/how-to-draw-font-awesome-icons-onto-html-canvas?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa .. hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry:      context.font = FontAwesome;

Comment: @NicoHaase:      I link it like this(in the <head>):    
`@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}`

Comment: @KrunalShah: I have read this article, but it doesn't fix it. In that question, he just use the old version of fontawesome. Now, I want to use the new version fontawesome.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to @TanDuong correct statement, it seems you even need to set the font-weight to 900 for the font to kick in...

Also note that [Chrome 76+](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001781) now requires that the font is [explicitly loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/load), or that one of the characters using the font is present in the document (targeting only the canvas through CSS is not possible anymore).

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
const font = '900 48px "Font Awesome 5 Free"';
// Chrome 76+ won't load the font
// until it's needed by the ducument (i.e one of the characters is displayed)
// or explicitely loaded through FontFaceSet API.
document.fonts.load(font).then((_) => {
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  // note that I wasn't able to find \uF006 defined in the provided CSS
  // falling back to fa-bug for demo
  ctx.fillText("\uF188", 50, 50);
})
```

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: It is really nice @Kaiido. I think this is correct answer

Comment: Your answer actually shows the same empty rectangle for me

Comment: @Marie Thanks for the heads up! Indeed it seems Chrome has made some changes since v76. [I opened an issue about it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001781), but for the time being I updated my answer to use a more bullet-proof solution to load the font. Note that it wasn't really related with the core of this answer, but still thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @Kaiido , Is this supported in IE > 9.

Answer (score 2):

In Font Awesome 5. You should use

`context.font = '48px Font Awesome 5 Free'`

In Font Awesome 4. You should use

`context.font = '48px FontAwesome'`

This is defined on [FontAwesome](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css). You can search `@font-face` to see what font name defined in Font Awesome 5

Comment: but when I : `<i id="fa">&#xf00b;</i>`, It can works. I don't if the unicode was wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I add a webfontloader.js, which makes it work perfect!

```
    <script src="./webfontloader.js"></script>
```

the webfontloader.js file can be found on the web.