# How to get a Font Awesome 5 icon as cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

In Font Awesome 4x I managed to set the cursor as an icon by changing it into a base-64 image url. Now in Font Awesome 5 it does not work any more.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49729772/7379503) solution, but it's not working here.

This is what I've tried.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 20;
canvas.height = 20;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
    ctx.font = "400 20px Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    setTimeout(function() {
        ctx.fillText("\uf2ed", 10, 10)
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        $('#foo').css('cursor', 'url(' + dataURL + '), auto');
    }, 200)
})
```

All I get is a black square 20x20

Is there anyone who knows how to get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the below example ...

```js
var hex = 0xF25A;
var unicode = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));

var canvas = document.getElementById("cache");
canvas.width = 64; canvas.height = 64;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font = '900 32px "Font Awesome 5 Free"';
context.fillText(unicode, canvas.width/2, canvas.width/2);
  
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor', 'url(' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png') + '), auto');
});
```

```css
html, body {height: 100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding: 0;}
canvas#cache {display: none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-wnAC7ln+XN0UKdcPvJvtqIH3jOjs9pnKnq9qX68ImXvOGz2JuFoEiCjT8jyZQX2z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="cache"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works very well.

Comment: This answer only works if you change the first line to a string: `var hex = "F25A"` OR if you remove `parseInt` from the second line and pass the raw hex value: `.fromCharCode(0xF25A)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I was successful using [jquery.awesomecursor](https://jwarby.github.io/jquery-awesome-cursor/), and this JS:

```
   $('body').awesomeCursor('cut', {color: '#3097d1',
                                    font: {cssClass: 'far fa-%s',
                                           family:'"Font Awesome 5 Pro"'
                                          }
                                   });
```

The key things here were:
. The cssClass for FontAwesome 5 ("regular" icons are 'far fa-X', not 'fa fa-X' as they were in prior versions)
. The way "family" is specified - I needed the inner set of quotes to make it work.

FWIW, I'm using this with WebPack so I needed to make sure faCut was loaded from "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons"; You can read more about this [here](https://www.pullrequest.com/blog/webpack-fontawesome-guide/).