# How to avoid Font Awesome loading/"jumping" when opening a page?

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome for icons on my website, but looks like the icons show up a bit later than the page content (especially noticeable in Firefox, in Chrome and IE it is a bit better):

[image]

Is there any way to avoid loading/"jumping" like this when opening a page?

Tried async and not async versions.

Comment: Do you download fonts in `<head>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712242/wait-for-fonts-to-load-before-rendering-web-page

Comment: Yes, in <head>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I switched to CSS version instead of JS, looks like it solved the issue.

Comment: Probably a good idea to download it too, rather than use the CDN.