# Change the Arabic fonts-family in the label and the options of an mat-select and mat-input Material angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template, angular5, angular-material-5

How Can I change the  fonts-family in the label and the options of an mat-select and mat-input Material angular 5 ?

i tried to apply the style directly on the elements mat-select and input but nothing worked for me.

myform-component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-2 col-4">
  <mat-select style="font-family: 'GE-Flow-Bold', sans-serif; font-size:12px" [ngModel]="selectedCivilite" formControlName='civiliteAr' (ngModelChange)="civiliteChanged($event)" placeholder="اللقب" >
    <mat-option style="font-family: 'GE-Flow-Bold', sans-serif; font-size:12px" [value]="v" *ngFor='let v of listCiviliteAr , index as i '>
      {{ v }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field  class="col-sm-5 col-8 arabic-text">
  <input style="font-family: 'GE-Flow-Bold', sans-serif; font-size:12px"  matInput formControlName='nomAr' placeholder="الإسم الشخصي" >
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('nomAr').invalid">{{getErrorNameArMessage()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the font is loaded in **index.html** like:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

then the form field would be rendered before the fonts loaded and will cause a sizing problem.

I think This will help:
[Wait for fonts to load before rendering web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712242/wait-for-fonts-to-load-before-rendering-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this style to the **mat-form-field**

```
font-family: 'GE-Flow-Bold', sans-serif
```

Should do the trick. Keep in mind that the font must be loaded so it is available for your application.

Comment: Then you don't have the font loaded in your application. Change it to font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; and you will see that the font is changing bc every browser (usually) knows this font.

Comment: The font is loaded in the app; it appears in other places like paragraphs