# Converting webfonts to base64 removes original font line-heights

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to wait for fonts to load before rendering my web page. One suggest that converting to base64 could be the best solution by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794798/11866037). So I converted using [fontsquirrel webfont generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)(also chose `Truetype Hinting: Keep Hinting`) and used in my file as

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url(...) format("woff"), url("montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
 }
```

But when I check on webpage, the original spacing of the font are removed. 
 
This is `before` using base64 
 
[image]

And this is `after` using base64 
 
[image] 
As you can see, spacing are removed, how do I prevent this ?

Comment: Could you try to set `letter-spacing` rule?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I just did but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you put up a working snippet - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example but it looks more like a line height problem than a letter spacing one. Try setting line-height explicitly and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `Font Squirrel` as they discussed in [github](https://github.com/ms-studio/karmilla/issues/34#issuecomment-178269855). While generating in their http://fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, enabling to `No Adjustment` for `Vertical Merics:`(in Expert) fixes the issue.