# i' m using font embed in my website. first time take more time load font

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

I'm using @font-face to embed fonts in my website. First the text renders as the system default, and then (once the font file has loaded presumably) the correct font renders a fraction of a second later. Is there a way to minimise/get rid of this delay, by delaying the page rendering until after fon

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52763507/9256189)

Comment: i'm already using this preload link but still not working