# javascript execution after fonts are loaded

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, font-face

I want to render some text in canvas using a particular font. But the text is drawn before text font is loaded.

I've tried to use `document.fonts.ready.then()` but apparently has no effect

This is at first load

[image]

This is when reloading (font in cache)

[image]

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgzt2f9s/)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
function draw()
{
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.canvas.width = 150;
  ctx.canvas.height = 150;

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.font = "40px Special Elite";   
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";   
  ctx.fillText("hello", 25, 50);
}

document.fonts.ready.then(function()
{
    draw();
});
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Special+Elite');
```

I'm also trying locally with this css, but I have the same results

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "custom_font";
    src: url("some_font_file.ttf");
}
```

How can I draw the text only once the font is loaded?

Comment: Did any of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712242/wait-for-fonts-to-load-before-rendering-web-page) help you?   Or any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wait+for+font+to+load)?

Comment: The problem with your current code is that the font isn't used anywhere before `draw()` is being called. So the browser didn't put it in the *list of resources that need to be dowloaded before `document.fonts.ready` resolves*. You need to explicitly tell the browser to load that font.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, load the font file in the head tag (don't forget to remove the @import line):

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/specialelite/v18/XLYgIZbkc4JPUL5CVArUVL0ntnAOSA.woff2" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom **async font loader** method like this:

```js
let fonts = [
  {
    "font-family": "Special Elite",
    "font-style": "normal",
    "font-weight": 400,
    src:
      "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/specialelite/v18/XLYgIZbkc4JPUL5CVArUVL0ntnAOSA.woff2"
  }
];

drawToCanvas();

async function drawToCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  //load fonts 
  await loadFonts(fonts);

  ctx.canvas.width = 150;
  ctx.canvas.height = 150;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "40px Special Elite";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText("hello", 25, 50);
}



async function loadFonts(fontsToLoad) {
  if (fontsToLoad.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fontsToLoad.length; i++) {
      let fontProps = fontsToLoad[i];
      let fontFamily = fontProps["font-family"];
      let fontWeight = fontProps["font-weight"];
      let fontStyle = fontProps["font-style"];
      let fontUrl = Array.isArray(fontProps["src"])
        ? fontProps["src"][0][0]
        : fontProps["src"];
      if (fontUrl.indexOf("url(") === -1) {
        fontUrl = "url(" + fontUrl + ")";
      }
      let fontFormat = fontProps["src"][0][1] ? fontProps["src"][1] : "";
      const font = new FontFace(fontFamily, fontUrl);
      font.weight = fontWeight;
      font.style = fontStyle;
      await font.load();
      document.fonts.add(font);
      console.log(fontFamily, "loaded");

      // apply font styles to body
      let fontDOMEl = document.createElement("div");
      fontDOMEl.textContent = "";
      document.body.appendChild(fontDOMEl);
      fontDOMEl.setAttribute(
        "style",
        `position:fixed; height:0; width:0; overflow:hidden; font-family:${fontFamily}; font-weight:${fontWeight}; font-style:${fontStyle}`
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

Open the google font css URL to get the actual font file
`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Special+Elite`
will return something like this (depending on your browser)

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Special Elite';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/specialelite/v18/XLYgIZbkc4JPUL5CVArUVL0ntnAOSA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Copy the src to the fonts object array (you can add multiple fonts):

```
let fonts = [
  {
    "font-family": "Special Elite",
    "font-style": "normal",
    "font-weight": 400,
    src:
      "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/specialelite/v18/XLYgIZbkc4JPUL5CVArUVL0ntnAOSA.woff2"
  }
];
```

Make you drawing function asynchronous

```
async function drawToCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // wait for fonts 
  await loadFonts(fonts);

  ctx.canvas.width = 150;
  ctx.canvas.height = 150;
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "40px Special Elite";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText("hello", 25, 50);
}
```